# Записать BitmapImage в MemoryStream

Tags: c#, wpf

Как записать изображение `BitmapImage` в `MemoryStrem` в WPF, если не использовать `System.Drawing`.

Comment: А что такое «изображение `Bitmap`»? В каком виде оно доступно?

Comment: @VladD Ошибся, то-есть записать объект `BitmapImage`.

Comment: А `bitmapImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png)` не пробовали?

Comment: @VladD Да, у `BitmapImage` нет такого метода.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676/bitmapimage-to-byte

Comment: @FoggyFinder Спасибо!

Comment: @FoggyFinder Если хотите, можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы записать [`BitmapImage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage) в [`MemoryStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream) можно воспользоваться абстрактным классом [`BitmapEncoder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder), а точнее одной из его реализаций.

Нас интересует метод [`Save`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.save)

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]
public virtual void Save (System.IO.Stream stream);
```

который как раз и позволяет записать растровое изображение в указанный поток.

Пример взят из ответа [`chrfin`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472434/chrfin)на SO к вопросу [BitmapImage to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676/bitmapimage-to-byte)

```
byte[] data;
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(ms);
    data = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Конечно, вместо `JpegBitmapEncoder` можно использовать любой другой `BitmapEncoder`, который бы был более подходящим под задачу.